# Problem with prop type in ToDo written in React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a very simple ToDo app composed of two components:

```
interface ToDoItemProps {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  done: boolean;
}

const ToDoItem = ({ id, text, done }: ToDoItemProps) => {
  return (
    <li key={id}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={done} />
      {text}
    </li>
  );
};

const TodoApp = () => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((todo) => {
                return <ToDoItem todo={todo} />
            })}
        </ul>

    )
};
```

In `ToDoApp` component, I get a prop `todo` with red underline  and information that:

```
TS2322: Type '{ todo: { id: number; text: string; done: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ToDoItemProps'.
  Property 'todo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ToDoItemProps'.
```

[image]

I compared how others do ToDos in React/TypeScript, and I found it done the same way. Could it be a problem with my IDE?

Comment: It's telling you exactly the right thing - per your definition of a `ToDoItem`, `<ToDoItem todo={todo} />` is **not** valid usage.

Comment: You haven't given any information on what's contained in `todos`. Clearly the contents of `todos` can't be implicitly mapped to your defined props.

Answer (score 2):

The interface `ToDoItemProps` defines the following props: `id`, `text` and `done`. None of them is called `todo`.

If these props *are actually the properties of a new `ToDo` interface*, then we can rewrite your example as:

```
interface ToDoItemProps {
  todo: ToDo
}

interface ToDo {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  done: boolean;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Actually I tried it before but in a wrong way. I corrected my solution now as per your suggestion with a little different naming.

Answer (score 0):

This how todoApp props should be written

```
const TodoApp = () => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((todo) => {
                 return <ToDoItem 
                          id={todo.id}
                          dono={todo.done}
                          text={todo.text}
                        />}
             }              
        </ul>

    )
};
```

or using spread operator

```
const TodoApp = () => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {todos.map((todo) => {
                 return <ToDoItem {...todo} />        
             }}        
        </ul>

    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue in the following way:
I added new interface as per @cmolina comment for ToDoItem and I corrected prop destructuring. I also added  for accessibility in ToDoItem.tsx

**ToDoInterfaces.ts:**

```
export interface ToDoItemProps {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  done: boolean;
}
```

**ToDoApp.tsx was left as it was:**

```
const ToDoApp = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo) => {
        return <ToDoItem todo={todo} />;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

**ToDoItem.tsx**:

```
import { ToDoItemProps } from "./ToDoInterfaces";

interface Props {
  todo: ToDoItemProps;
}

const ToDoItem = ({ todo }: Props) => {
  const { id, done, text } = todo;

  return (
    <li key={id}>
       <input type="checkbox" id={`task${id}`} checked={done} />
       <label htmlFor={`task${id}`}>{text}</label>
    </li>
  );
};
```